# Вывести значение битового поля

Tags: c++

Можно ли в C++ вывести в консоль значение битового поля, относящегося к определенной структуре? Если да, то как?

Answer (score 4):

Выводите как обычно:

```
#include <iostream>

struct Foo {
   unsigned bar : 3;
   unsigned baz : 6;
};

int main() {
    Foo foo;
    foo.bar = 2;
    foo.baz = 4;
    std::cout << foo.bar << std::endl;
    std::cout << foo.baz << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Если нужно в двоичном виде, то:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <bitset>

struct Foo {
   unsigned bar : 3;
   unsigned baz : 6;
};

int main() {
    Foo foo;
    foo.bar = 2;
    foo.baz = 4;
    std::cout << std::bitset<3>(foo.bar) << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::bitset<6>(foo.baz) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```